# Where should I add to an additional partition?

Tags: partitioning, mount

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
Recently, my home directory became full, so I tried to add an additional partition. (It was originally used a shared storage between Linux-Windows system since I'm using dual boot system on my laptop.)

At first, I just made a directory below /mnt and mounted the new partition at. Then, system alerted me "root partition is full".
So, I had to unmount the partition.

Could someone teach me where should I mount an additional partition?
What is the proper mount point in my case?

Below is the result of 'df -h'.
The additional partition is /dev/sda8 which isn't present because I unmounted it.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.2G   33M  1.2G   3% /run
/dev/sda6        23G   11G   12G  49% /
tmpfs           5.9G   22M  5.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda7        55G   28G   25G  53% /home
/dev/sda3        96M   34M   63M  35% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1.2G  180K  1.2G   1% /run/user/1000
```

I remount /dev/sda8 and this is the result.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.2G   93M  1.1G   8% /run
/dev/sda6        23G   11G   12G  49% /
tmpfs           5.9G   22M  5.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda7        55G   28G   25G  53% /home
/dev/sda3        96M   34M   63M  35% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1.2G  180K  1.2G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda8        28G  9.0G   18G  35% /mnt/ext
```

If mounting a partition at /mnt/ext didn't make the root partition full, then why suddenly system alerted me? I checked the usage at that time, root partition was definitely full;

Comment: Mounting a partition does not use up the space in the / partition. Can you remount /dev/sd8 (whereever you want) and publish the result of  `df -h`?

Comment: It doesn't matter where it's mounted. There is no "proper mount point" for your particular case. It will also not help with home being full.

Comment: @mikewhatever,  then how I could fix the problem of full of my home directory?

Comment: Your `/home` partition is not full; it has 25GB of free space...

Comment: @fkraiem, that's because I moved and delete many datas;;

Comment: You should mount additional partitions in `/media`, but I am not really clear about what is happening for you...

Comment: @Julian Exactly the way you've done already. Delete or move files, and if you want a bigger home, repartition.

Comment: @Zanna, thank you for clearing it. I thought I should mount it another mount point other than /mnt or /media, otherwise, it would count as system's usage of root directory.

Comment: And I don't know why but suddenly root directory became full. Well, anyway it must be because I did something wrong. T_T

Comment: @mikewhatever, repartition means that I need to re-install my system?
I've recently learned about lvm, though it can't fix my problem because I didn't make my file system as lvm at first, can it?

Comment: No, LVM just makes things complicated imho. If your root directory is suddenly becoming full, is a log file growing crazily or something? As others pointed out, the system shouldn't care about the mountpoint when reporting the disk usage...

Comment: @Zanna,  just checked this. Really appreciate your answer cleared the part. Wish you have a good day :-)